# Time series forecasting with a combination of methods

Tags: time-series, forecasting, forecast-combination

So,
i read this article: https://www.r-bloggers.com/timeseries-forecasting-using-extreme-gradient-boosting/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+RBloggers+%28R+bloggers%29

And i want to ask if it is sensible to forecast a time series like in the article - ARIMA, then forecast with THETA method and then calculate the average of those 2 results. Or even averaging the results from 3 and more methods?
You can completely disregard the part with R and RStudio with the code and all. My question is strictly theoretical if such an approach would be a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's called a forecast combination and is used widely in practice. for instance, take a look at the second paragraph on the second page of [this document](https://www.federalreserve.gov/bankinforeg/model-changes-20160217.pdf), where the Federal Reserve Bank explains how it projects operational losses of banks:

> the Federal Reserve will estimate historically-based loss
>   projections using an average of two models

It does precisely what you just described: it averages the losses porojected by two models. It's a simple average.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it generally is a decent idea and likely will improve forecast accuracy. To get a better idea for your specific time-series, you should perform time-series cross-validation on the models and combinations.

Well cited paper on the potential benefits of forecast combinations: http://repository.upenn.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1005&context=marketing_papers